# Python list index out of range issue OCR response

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, numbers

I am trying to make a python script that adds the numbers in the OCR response to a python dictionary. A normal response should look something like this:

EXAMPLE:

```
16375 N. Kashington St. 
Thornton, CO 80023
2X Member 111826278335
673919 FF BS BREAST     23.99 E
633561 KS DICED TOH
967596 JACKORGSALSR     2.97 E
3 e 4.29
878137 18CT EGGS        12.87 E
77053 GRAPE TOMATO      6.29 E
404609 ECO HALF PAN     6.49 a
55992 GRND TURKEY       18.47 E
263423 CHPD ONION       3.59 E
22101 MONT JACK 4.45 E
SUBTOTAL        85.61
TAX     3.52
TOTAL
Check/Hember Prntd      89.13
0.00
A 8.50% TAX
E 3.75% TAX     2.97
TOTAL TAX       3.52
TOTAL NUMBER OF ITEMS SOLD -
15:00 629 4 172 14
OP#: 14 Name: PEPPER
Thank You !
Please Come fÄ9ain
Whse:629 Trm:f Trn:172
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
1 w ilei #687   
525 Alakawa St
Honolulu, HI 96817
IE      Member
E       1048072 GREEK YOGURT    6.29 A
E       633561 KS DICED TOM     6.59 A
E       57554 BLUEBERRIES       6.99
E       941275 KS PINE NUTS     24.99 A
1294528 ORG OATMEAL     7.99
SUBTOTAL        52.85
TAX     2.49
TOTAL
```

SPECIFIC:

```
392012 EGGS 9.99
293029 2x MILK 3.99
893929 3x SODA 2 10.99

to

[392012, 9.99]
[293029, 3.99]
[893929, 10.99]
```

The program has been designed so it first extracts only numbers, splits the list, finds which values are item numbers and what are prices, and matches the dictionary values. However, the code does not work for line 2 or 3 in the example where it returns j(1) list index out of range as it is picking up the value '2x' or '3x' instead of the price. I have been struggling on making this program work on a wide variety of responses and this issue so any help will be appreciated!

Code:

```
OCRFiltered = OCRText.translate({ord(i): None for i in ',:\/!@#$%^&*()_-+=;[]`~<>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'})
OCRInline = OCRFiltered.split('\n')
OCRInline = [ OCRInline.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')  for OCRInline in OCRInline ]
print(OCRInline)
global itemnumberslist
itemnumberslist = []
global itemprices
itemprices = {}
for l in OCRInline:
    j = l.split(' ')
    while('' in j) : 
        j.remove('')
    print(j)
    #print('LIST ITEMS ', j)
    if len(j) == 2:
        if len(j[0]) == 7 or len(j[0]) == 6 or len(j[0]) == 5 and len(j[1]) >= 3:
            try:
                number = int(j[0])
                price = float(j[1])
                print(number, price)
                itemprices[number] = price
                itemnumberslist.append(number)
            except:
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

It's way easier to accomplish using regex.

```py
    import re

    str1 = "392012 EGGS 9.99"
    str2 = "293029 2x MILK 3.99"
    str3 = "893929 3x SODA 2 10.99"
    
    strings = [str1, str2, str3]

    itemnumberslist = []

    for string in strings:
        num_re = re.compile(r"[\d.]+")
        matches = num_re.findall(string)
        itemnumberslist.append([int(matches[0]), float(matches[-1])])

    print(itemnumberslist)
```

Output:

> [392012, 9.99]

> [293029, 3.99]

> [893929, 10.99]

Hopefully, that'll help accomplish what you're trying to do. You can tweak it to your liking. It worked in my testing based on the examples you submitted.

**EDITED SCRIPT:**

```py
    import re


    def item_numbers_list(txt):
        num_re = re.compile(r"(?<=\s)(?:(?:\d+\.)?\d+)(?=[\s])")
        try_shorten = re.findall(".+\n(?=SUBTOTAL)", txt, re.DOTALL)[0]
        if try_shorten: txt = try_shorten
        txt = re.sub(r"(.+)", r" \g<1> ", txt)
        match_list = []
        for i in txt.splitlines():
            matches = num_re.findall(i)
            if len(matches) != 2: continue
            match_list.append({int(matches[0]): float(matches[1])})
        return match_list
```

Comment: Yes, if you split the string on newlines', by doing either: "str".split("\n") or "str".splitlines()

Comment: Could you show how your strings are built? So that I could come up with a better solution.

Comment: An example response:

Comment: 16375 N. Kashington St. 
Thornton, CO 80023
2X Member 111826278335
673919 FF BS BREAST     23.99 E
633561 KS DICED TOH
967596 JACKORGSALSR     2.97 E
3 e 4.29
878137 18CT EGGS        12.87 E
77053 GRAPE TOMATO      6.29 E
404609 ECO HALF PAN     6.49 a
55992 GRND TURKEY       18.47 E
263423 CHPD ONION       3.59 E
22101 MONT JACK 4.45 E
SUBTOTAL        85.61
TAX     3.52
TOTAL
Check/Hember Prntd      89.13
0.00
A 8.50% TAX
E 3.75% TAX     2.97
TOTAL TAX       3.52
TOTAL NUMBER OF ITEMS SOLD -
15:00 629 4 172 14
OP#: 14 Name: PEPPER
Thank You !

Comment: The lines are usually broken in the response

Comment: I was looking for it to return: ItemNumberList:  [673919, 967596, 77053, 404609, 55992, 263423, 22101]
Item Prices:  {673919: 23.99, 967596: 2.97, 77053: 6.29, 404609: 6.49, 55992: 18.47, 263423: 3.59, 22101: 4.45}

Comment: What do you mean by broken? Could you send another example? Are these receipts?

Comment: I have updated my question to include 2 examples, what I meant by broken was split by line, and these are receipt data.